# Multi select dropdown - how to add default value

Tags: php, default-value, multi-select

I'm trying to add default value in multiselect dropdown,
so far i tried

```
    <select name="addons[]" multiple="multiple" id="addons">
     <option value="Not Selected" <?php echo set_select('addons[]', 'Not Selected', TRUE); ?> >Not Selected</option>
    <?php foreach ($addons as $options) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $options->addon_name; ?>"><h5><?php echo $options->addon_name; ?></h5></option>
    <?php } ?>                 
 </select>
```

I should suppose to get the default value as **"Not selected"** but i'm getting only empty.
Any one knows where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: what does echo set_select('addons[]', 'Not Selected', TRUE); do

Comment: Are you setting the html selected attribute correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="addons[]" multiple="multiple" id="addons">
 <option value="Not Selected" 
<?php echo in_array("Not Selected",$addons)?"SELECTED":"" ?> 
>Not Selected</option>
<?php foreach ($addons as $options) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $options->addon_name; ?>" 
    <?php echo in_array($options->addon_name,$addons)?"SELECTED":"" ?>
    ><h5><?php echo $options->addon_name; ?></h5></option>
<?php } ?>                 
</select>
```

where $addons is for example the $_POST['addons'] or the array of current addons from your database.

By the way: I think you should not use < h5 > inside the < option > tag

Comment: +1 if you are selecting the $addons option, then there is no need to select the "not selected" option, as its the first option and is automatically the default.

Comment: yes you are right. I would not implement the Not Selected option. Its useless and confusing for the user particularly because its a multi-select. "Not selected" is the case if nothing is selected. There is no need to show it as an option!!!